# Checking if a certain letter comes x spaces after another in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm solving Coderbyte problems, and came across one called ABCheck, which takes a string and returns `true` if the letter 'a' and b are separated by exactly three places. I know there's an easier way to do this with regexes, but I'm trying to do it the logical way first, for learning purposes.

Here's the code I have:

```
def ABCheck(str)
  str = str.downcase.split('')
  str.each_with_index do |char,index|
    if char == 'a' && str[index+4] == 'b'
      return "true"
    elsif 
    char == 'b' && str[index+4] == 'a'
      return "true"
    else
      return "false"
    end
  end
end

ABCheck("Laura sobs")
```

My code isn't returning the correct answer. It returns `false` even though the answer should be `true`.

Comment: It is not clear what "the letter 'a' is separated by the letter 'b' by 3 places (and vice versa)" means. You should exemplify that.

Comment: Keep in mind that once the `return` statement is reached your function stops (and your loop too). You can solve the problem if you put `return "false"` after the loop.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here is the question directly from the site. I think they are better at explaining it than I am. **Have the function ABCheck(str) take the str parameter being passed and return the string true if the characters a and b are separated by exactly 3 places anywhere in the string at least once**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "a and b are separated by exactly 3 places" cannot be paraphrased as " 'a' is separated by the letter 'b' by 3 places (and vice versa)". The latter is nonsense.

Comment: You seem to be implying that using a regex is not logical. In what way is it not logical? Can you explain? And what kind of solutions would qualify as a logical solution?

Comment: I see. I apologize about that. I edited the original question due to this. I do not mean it is not logical, but I would like to learn how to do it the "long way" and challenge my mind before using a regex.

Comment: Recall that the Ruby convention is to use snake-case (lower-case letters and the underscore `_`) for the names of methods and variables, so you might call your method `ab_check`. Since the method returns `true` or `false`, you should consider ending the name with a questions mark, as @Arkku has done.  Note also that Arkku made the number of intervening spaces an argument (with a default value), to make the method more general.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you only check the first character – if that first character is not `a` or `b` meeting the search condition, you immediately return `"false"`. You need to search through *all* the possible positions in the string before you know that none of the matched.

(This is a common pattern when searching for a match in some sort of collection; if you find it you can return immediately, but if you don't you must keep searching until the end.)

Also note that you return the *string* `"false"`, not the boolean `false`.

Example solution (without regex):

```
def axb_match?(str, in_between = 3)
  distance = in_between + 1 # chars in between + the 'b'
  str, i = str.downcase, -1
  while i = str.index('a', i + 1)
    return true if (str[i + distance] == 'b') || (i >= distance && str[i - distance] == 'b')
  end
  false # no match was found (finding would return immediately)
end
axb_match? "Laura sobs" # -> true
```

And of course with regex it's quite simple:

```
str =~ /(a...b)|(b...a)/i
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. :) I really do appreciate your answers. And the regex is so clean.

Answer (score 2):

As @Arkku diagnosed your problem I will confine my comments to an alternative method for the non-regex solution. (In real life you certainly would want to use a regular expression.)

The Ruby way, as I see it, would be to use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) rather than indices:

```
def a3b_match?(str)
  str.each_char.each_cons(5).any? { |f,*_,l|
    (f=='a' && l=='b') || (f=='b' && l=='a') }
end

a3b_match?('xadogbite')   #=> true
a3b_match?('xbdogaite')   #=> true
a3b_match?('xbdgaite')    #=> false
a3b_match?('xadoggybite') #=> false
```

If you instead wanted the number of matches, change [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) to [Enumerable#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).

Here are the steps:

```
str = 'xadogbite'
enum0 = str.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "xadogbite":each_char> 
enum1 = enum0.each_cons(5)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "xadogbite":each_char>:each_cons(5)>
```

Carefully examine the return values for the calculations of the enumerators `enum0` and `enum1`. You can think of `enum1` as a "compound" enumerator.

We can see the (five) values of `enum1` that `any?` will pass into the block by converting that enumerator to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["x", "a", "d", "o", "g"],
  #    ["a", "d", "o", "g", "b"],
  #    ["d", "o", "g", "b", "i"],
  #    ["o", "g", "b", "i", "t"],
  #    ["g", "b", "i", "t", "e"]]
```

Let's simulate the passing of the first value of `enum1` into the block and assign it to the block variables<sup>1</sup>:

```
f,*m,l = enum1.next
f #=> "x" 
m #=> ["a", "d", "o"]
l #=> "g"
```

We then perform the block calculation:

```
(f=='a' && l=='b') || (f=='b' && l=='a') }
  #=> ('x'=='a' && 'g'=='b') || ('x'=='b' && 'g'=='a') }
  #=> false || false => false
```

`any?` must therefore pass the next element of `enum1` into the block:

```
 f,*_,l = enum1.next
   #=> ["a", "d", "o", "g", "b"]
 f #=> "a"
 l #=> "b"

(f=='a' && l=='b') || (f=='b' && l=='a') }
  #=> ('a'=='a' && 'b'=='b') => true
```

Since we have a match on `(f=='a' && l=='b')`, there is no need for Ruby to evaluate `(f=='b' && l=='a')` or to perform similar calculations for the rest of the elements of `enum1`, so she doesn't. `any?` returns `true`.

<sup>1 I used the local variable `m` instead of `_` because IRB uses the latter for its own purpose. When run from the command line, `_` works just fine.</sup>

Comment: I agree, the use of `each_*` is more Ruby-like than my solution.

Comment: WOW, thank you both SO much. That helps me comprehend this much better and gives me a better understanding of this. Thank you.